# Html2canvas for each div export to pdf separately

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I have Page, It has 6 div with same class name "exportpdf", I am converting those div into pdf using **jspdf** and **html2canvas**

```
var elementTobePrinted = angular.element(attrs.selector),
iframeBody = elementTobePrinted.contents().find('div.exportpdf');
```

In html2canvas.....

```
html2canvas(elementTobePrinted, {
  onrendered: function (canvas) {
    var doc = new jsPDF();     
    for(var i=1;i<elementTobePrinted.length;i++){
      doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"), 'jpeg', 15, 40, 180, 160);
      doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"),'JPEG', 0, 0, 215, 40)
      doc.addPage();
    } 

    doc.save(attrs.fileName);
}
```

I converted page to canvas.its create same div contents for whole pdf. I need each div contents into same pdf with different pages.

Can anyone help me?

The problem is with html2canvas:

```
doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"), 'jpeg', 15, 40,180, 160);
```

Here I need to pass `elementTobePrinted` list to addImage.

Answer (score 3):

On angular 2(now 6) framework.
u can use the logic as below,

- On click execute `generateAllPdf()` function,
- gather all `6 id's` from my html collection,
- iterate through each `id` and call `html2canvas` function,
- as `html2canvas` runs in background to process images, i m using
  `await` on function,
- after the `html2canvas` completes its process, i ll save the
  document,
- If suppose i wont use `await` i ll end-up in downloading an empty
  page.

below is my code logic,

```
// As All Functions in js are asynchronus, to use await i am using async here
 async generateAllPdf() {
    const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
    const options = {
      pagesplit: true
    };
    const ids = document.querySelectorAll('[id]');
    const length = ids.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      const chart = document.getElementById(ids[i].id);
      // excute this function then exit loop
      await html2canvas(chart, { scale: 1 }).then(function (canvas) { 
        doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'), 'JPEG', 10, 50, 200, 150);
        if (i < (length - 1)) {
          doc.addPage();
        }
      });
    }
    // download the pdf with all charts
    doc.save('All_charts_' + Date.now() + '.pdf');
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue here is that `elementTobePrinted`is not what you think it is.

When you run the code:

```
var elementTobePrinted = angular.element(attrs.selector)
```

This will return you a list of every element that matches the conditions, so you said you have 6 of these elements ("It has 6 divs").

Have you tried replacing:

```
html2canvas(elementTobePrinted, {
  onrendered: function (canvas) {
    var doc = new jsPDF();     
    for(var i=1;i<elementTobePrinted.length;i++) {
      doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"), 'jpeg', 15, 40, 180, 160);
      doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"),'JPEG', 0, 0, 215, 40)
      doc.addPage();
    } 
    doc.save(attrs.fileName);
}
```

With...

```
for(var i=0; i<elementTobePrinted.length; i++){
  html2canvas(elementTobePrinted[i], {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
      var doc = new jsPDF();     
      doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"), 'jpeg', 15, 40, 180, 160);
      doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"),'JPEG', 0, 0, 215, 40)
      doc.addPage();
      doc.save(attrs.fileName);
    }
}
```

The reason I suggest this is that html2Canvas wants a **SINGLE** element as its first parameter and your example above passes a **list** of elements (I think, assuming `angular.element(attrs.selector)` finds all 6 divs you are trying to print).