# Angular 7 best way to export in pdf div content using html2canvas

Tags: javascript, angular, html2canvas, export-to-pdf

I'm facing a problem exporting in pdf a div with overflow-y to "auto".

I'm using html2canvas & jspdf to do this, but when I click on export, the pdf is generated but only with the visible part of the div. I saw a lot of links, with option for scrollTo(0) before, but I never success to export all then content div.

my component look like this :

```
<div id="printreport">
   <app-first-part>
   <app-second-part>
   <app-third-part>
   <app-fourth-part>
</div
```

Is there a way to export my div (id="printreport") with existing style, idealy with break page at each part ? Maybe another solution than html2canvas or jspdf ? The real need is to print with styles, not necessary export in pdf.

maybe like print just some divs but how to keep style in this case ?

Thanks for help and suggestions !

Jeff

Comment: Are you using inline styling for those components?

Comment: each component use a .scss file and some common styles are in the global style.scss file

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to do what I want. here is the link that help me a lot !
[Html2canvas for each div export to pdf separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784777/html2canvas-for-each-div-export-to-pdf-separately)

particulary the JpG answer.

here is my final code :

```
 async printRapport() {
  this.spinnerService.showSpinner();

  const doc = new jspdf('l', 'mm', 'a4');
  const options = {
    pagesplit: true
  };
  const ids = document.querySelectorAll('[id]');
  console.log(ids);
  const length = ids.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    const bloc = document.getElementById(ids[i].id);
    // excute this function then exit loop
    await html2canvas(bloc, { scale: 1 }).then(function (canvas) {
      doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'), 'JPEG', 10, 10, 277,canvas.height*0.2);
      if (i < (length - 1)) {
        doc.addPage();
      }
    });
  }
  // download the pdf with all charts
  doc.save('rapport_' + this.detailPanier.name.replace(/\s/g, '_') + '.pdf'); // Generated PDF*!/
  this.spinnerService.hideSpinner();
}
```

you can notate that all the div to print must have an id in the html.

Thanks all !
Bye